# Binding a visible parameter to an 'or' statement in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to bind a visible property to be true when one of two conditions are true. Something like the following -

```
 $(document.getElementById("ddlTest")).attr("data-bind", "options:  $root.Plan, optionsValue:'PlanNameId', optionsText:'PlanName', value: $root.PlanTest, optionsCaption: 'Select', visible: TestId() !== 3 || 4 || 5");
```

Code is working fine only one condition but I want multiple OR condition for `visible`

Comment: PS. @Tanner's answer is spot on, but know that code a la `[3,4,5].indexOf(TestId()) >= 0`  also works and may be more friendly if you don't always have exactly three values to test for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to repeat `TestId()` for each comparison:

```
visible: (TestId() !== 3 || TestId() !== 4 || TestId() !== 5)
```

With comparisons like this, it would be cleaner in a function something like:

```
function isTestIdValid(){
   // your logic here - perhaps referencing observables directly?
   return (TestId() !== 3 || TestId() !== 4 || TestId() !== 5);
}
```

I'm not sure what your observables are named, otherwise just pass a parameter to the function to evaluate.

Then your markup will look like this:

```
visible: isTestIdValid()
```

**UPDATE**

As @Hans suggests you could also use a [KO Computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to achieve this, something along the lines of:

```
this.isTestIdValid= ko.computed(function() {
      return (this.TestId() !== 3 || this.TestId() !== 4 || this.TestId() !== 5);
    }, this);
```

You will need to adapt this to fit your view model structure.

Comment: +1 for suggesting making this logic (and thus making it testable)

Comment: It would be slightly better even if you didn't use a function, but a computed observable. But +1 for removing the logic from the DOM.

Comment: @Hans was going to suggest that but there is limited details of the view model in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
visible: TestId() !== 3 || TestId() !== 4 || TestId() !== 5
```